# The method JasperFillManager.fillReport () throws java.io.Exception

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have the following exception when I launch my script in the development environment (SunOS 5.10 i86pc Solaris), I tried searching on google for hours trying various workarounds suggested but do not solve the problem.
In fact, trying to use super-user when I launch my script the report is generated, whereas with a normal user I get the following exception and the report is not generated.

`Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.<init>(SimpleFontFace.java:108)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.<init>(SimpleFontFace.java:128)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.getInstance(SimpleFontFace.java:67)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFamily.setNormal(SimpleFontFamily.java:99)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamily(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:261)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:232)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:193)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:162)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
        at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:967)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.<init>(SimpleFontFace.java:100)
        ... 50 more`

I noticed that the file is written to the temporary folder (/var/tmp) has permissions set to 600, how can I set the permissions in Jasper Report that these files must be?? Or should I re-check the permissions of / bin / java ?

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data. Can you send font? Do you have permission? I don't know, what is a font, is a font valid, permission etc.

Comment: the report is run with root works (I also changed when launching java.io.tmp, in the following way: java -Djava.io.tmp=/my/tmp/path -jar pdf.1.0.0.jar)

Comment: I think it's something related to umask command... can be??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the library can avoid compiling at runtime each time you invoke the method for genarazione PDF, filling the file.jasper directly with the data. The code fragment used is the following:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("<NAME OF FILE.JASPER>"); 
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
//Load bufferedInputStream file.jasper 
jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(bufferedInputStream); 
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,new JRBeanArrayDataSource(arrlist));
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"<NAME OF OUTPUT FILE>");
```

In this way it bypasses the problem!

Answer (score 2):

In some cases the cause is the running instance not being able to write to the 
Java temp directory (java.io.tmpdir).

If your are running it on tomcat maybe you deleted the temp directory of the tomcat installation, or the folder have wrong permissions.

(tomcat folder)/temp

Comment: I check folder permission ( for test i set chmod 777 for each folder impacted) but isn't resolve problem. I resolve the problem by filling report via file.JASPER (compile output of jrxml in ireport)